# jquery load script conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQuery to append a script tag to a div, ex.:

```
$("#special_div").append("<script src="http://blablabla.com/id.php?id=0000"></script>");
```

and that script returns:

```
document.write("<object ....></object>");
```

but when I append it, all my HTML is gone and only that  tag is written..

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Escape your quotes first of all:

```
$("#special_div")
  .append("<script src=\"http://blablabla.com/id.php?id=0000\"></script>");
```

Additionally document.write is fine depending on when it is called.

Edit: removed other text, other answerer about document.write enlightened me on this :D  Thanks @Ivo

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://javascript.about.com/library/blwrite.htm) is the explanation:

> Any document.write statement that runs after the page finishes loading will create a new page and overwrite all of the content of the current page

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong is that you're using `document.write()` — or at least the author of that script is using it. That's what `document.write()` does when it's called *after* the actual original document has been built by the browser. I suppose your code is in some jQuery initialization block:

```
$(function() {

  // your code somewhere in here ...

});
```

Thus it runs only when the browser has gotten the page all ready.  But at that point, a new call to `document.write()` will be interpreted as meaning that you want to *completely* replace the current page with new stuff.

One thing to try would be to put an `<iframe>` in the document (not with `document.write()`!!) and then put the `<script>` tag inside that.

Answer (score 0):

The script that you load uses `document.write`, but you're loading the script after the page has already been loaded completely, therefore `document.write` will overwrite the contents of the page.

For more reasons against the use of `document.write` see:
[Why is document.write considered a "bad practice"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

To fix it, you need to include the script in the HTML source itself.

Answer (score 0):

don't use document.write but appendChild to append the obejct tag